# How to fill a column based on adjacent column value in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

For example let's say, in Sheet 1 I have the below Columns

```
Column A..........Column B

Apple..............Val01

Ball...............Val02 

Cat................Val03

Dog................Val04
```

In Sheet 2, I have the same two columns but with 5000 rows.
Let's consider 5 rows for example,

```
Column A........... Column B
 
Dog

Ball

Apple

Cat

Cat
```

Now, in my Sheet 2, I have 5000 rows with Column A filled but I want to automate the filling of Column B based on the values present in Sheet 1. I have tried using the INDIRECT function but was not successful. I was using this formula `=INDIRECT( "'test!B" & MATCH(A1, test!A:A, 0))` where test is my sheet name. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong in this or if there's any other method to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'test'!B" & MATCH(A1, 'test'!A:A, 0))` or omit the `'` surrounding the sheet name :-)

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `INDEX` instead of `INDIRECT`

In `Sheet2!B1`

```
=INDEX(test!B:B,MATCH(A1,test!A:A,0))
```

And copy down to all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the attachment.
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))